# jquery animate won't work with css positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm just starting with jQuery and some basic animations. To be exact I use an image and make it go up after clicking on it:

```
$(function () {
    $('.rocket').click(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            bottom: 1000
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

I have a **css** file attached to the html code and I've set the position of the picture to relative, which works. But as soon as I set its position in css (left: some value; top: some value, etc) the picture won't move.

I manage to center in css only with margin. Is the margin property in the css the only way to set something in the center(or other place) or am I missing something?

Comment: look at my answer, you can't set a top value on css, if you want to animate bottom.

Comment: You can use CSS transform:translate also for changing position of an element.
No, margin is not the only way to center align an element. translate or flexbox can also be used.
In case you want to see transition, check this:  
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6049/

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you've set right your css, for example you can't set `top` if you want to animate bottom.

```js
$('.rocket').click(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                bottom: 1000
            }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
.container{
    position:relative;
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
}

.rocket{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="rocket">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but he put 2 **});** . One to close function and one before text start. I don't know if it's just a formatting error.

Comment: sorry, I miss the firsr '$(function()' cause bad formatting.